# How to highlight selection in QTreeView programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

When I choose a selection in the `QTreeView` programmatically using `item_selected('Item2')` the selection gets passed to the handler as expected. I would also like that item to have a selection highlight, but I can't seem to figure that out. Any ideas?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem
import sys


def item_selected(selection):
    try:
        print(selection.text(0))
    except AttributeError:
        print(selection)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

TreeList = ({
    'Header1': (('Item1', 'Item2', )),
    'Header2': (('Item11', 'Item21', )),
})

tree = QTreeWidget()

for key, value in TreeList.items():
    parent = QTreeWidgetItem(tree, [key])
    for val in value:
        child = QTreeWidgetItem([val])
        child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.addChild(child)

tree.itemClicked.connect(item_selected)

tree.show()

# SELECT AND HIGHLIGHT THIS ONE
item_selected('Item2')

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry if the above code is a mess.

Comment: You can use "selection.setBackground(0, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#FFFF00")))"

Comment: @NimishBansal That does not work if I pass the selection in using `item_selected('Item2')` since `selection` is not a `QTreeViewItem` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must not use the same slot, it receives an item, and only prints it, in your case you have to search the item for its text and select it:

```
def item_selected(selection):
    print(selection.text(0))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

TreeList = ({
    'Header1': (('Item1', 'Item2', )),
    'Header2': (('Item11', 'Item21', )),
})

tree = QTreeWidget()

for key, value in TreeList.items():
    parent = QTreeWidgetItem(tree, [key])
    for val in value:
        child = QTreeWidgetItem([val])
        child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.addChild(child)

tree.itemClicked.connect(item_selected)

items = tree.findItems("Item2", Qt.MatchFixedString| Qt.MatchRecursive) 
[it.setSelected(True) for it in items]

tree.expandAll()
tree.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I used a variation of this, but this answer put me on the right path. The answer works exactly as expected.